# What am I? Poem riddle

Tags: riddle

> 1. I am old and I am huge
> 2. I also am "beginning"
> 3. While someone, let me call him scrooge, just cheaply is producing
> 4. To get line one, the key gets split into more than one word
> 5. Line two includes Pope Gregory, whose system is preferred.
> 6. Finally line three will be the word in proper meaning. The other two are similar, but only when you're reading
> 7. One last tip, it may help you, Line two is not in english. The country where it's spoken in, was many years distinguished

I know the rhymes are not worth an oscar, but after 45 minutes, this is the best I came up with

PS: Line one refers to complete words, splitting a letter from it is not part of the clue

Hint 1:

> The country is well known for a certain thing since the distinguishment

Hint 2:

> The beginning doesn't refer to a single beginning

Hint 3:

> In line 3, "Scrooge" is not the term you should pay attention to

Hint 4:

> Line 6 doesn't just describe different meanings for the word in each line, cause line 1 describes two independent Words. But if you mount them together, you get one word that is written the same like the other two

Hint 5:

> The first word is french, but only the first syllable is needed

Hint 6:

> The "cheap producing" is referring to the action

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Gold.

'I am huge and old.'

> 'I am hu**g**e and **old**.'
>  The word was split, as you say.

'I also am "beginning".'

> Pope Gregory (XIII) created the Gregorian calendar, named after himself. I, however, see no mention of gold in the description of the calendar, at least on Wikipedia. Janus, the Roman God said to be represented by the month of January, was the God of beginnings and endings. Someone else help out!

'While someone, let me call him scrooge, just cheaply is producing'

> This is a reference to Disney's *DuckTales*, wherein Scrooge McDuck is an incredibly rich entrepreneur with a vault full of gold.

Comment: Good guess, but in the first line, you split the answer into "more than one word", and you have split it into a letter and a word

Comment: Let me explain some more:
1. You haven't split the word into two proper ones
2. This part has not really to do much with your answer
3. You just referred to half of it. The "cheaply producing" is not in your answer, and your reference also doesn't really produce cheaply